# Uploading files larger than 4gb in an IIS site?

Tags: iis, iis-10

IIS seems to have a limit to the size file it can upload of around 4gb

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/settings-schema/ms689462(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

How do you upload larger files than this?
Or is IIS just not suitable for an application that needs to be able to do that?

Comment: This is indeed the upload limit of IIS. So if you want to upload a larger file, it is recommended to split the file into multiple parts and upload them in multiple parts in the form of a stream.

Comment: Given an end user can't do that, does that mean that there is no way for an end user to upload a file bigger than 4GB with IIS?

Comment: Yes, but the method I said is split file through code, not let users split large file. You can use JS code to split file and upload one by one.

Comment: Do you have an example of JS code to split a file larger than 4GB?